# button shape with transparency and only dotted border

Tags: css, shapes

Is it able to create a button with transparent background and a dotted border, with a custom shape?

[image: transparent button with dotted border]

I'm able now to do this with a background color, but when I try to to fill the inner without any color, nothing works as expected.

```css
body{
  background: #999
}
button {
  height: 50px;
  width: 250px;
  border: dotted 1px #FFF;
  border-bottom: none;
  background: none;
  position: relative;
}
button:after,
button:before {
    content: '';
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    top: 100%;
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    border-style: solid;
}

button:after {
    border-color: #fff transparent transparent transparent;
    border-width: 1px 125px 0 0;
    right: 1px
}

button:before {   
   border-color: transparent transparent #fff transparent;
   border-width: 0 125px 1px 0;
   left: 0
}
```

```html
<body>
<button></button>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not so sure about a button, but you can certainly create shapes out of divs.

What you are looking for is a play with borders to create shapes.

```css
#triangle{
 width: 0;
 height: 0;
 border-left: 30px solid transparent;
 border-right: 30px solid transparent;
 border-bottom: 40px solid green;
}
```

```html
<div id="triangle"></div>
```

As you can see, I created a triangle with just the borders, the trick is to understand the borders of a div. They are not straight, their ends are wedge shaped.

I think this is a good starting point for you.